# Positioning elements on page CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to create page header as following:
[image]

but what I'm getting with my dummy css-rules:
[image]

I am mostly a backend developer, but I want to dive into CSS and HTML, here is my [Html struct](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/0570d544ed212c744ed8), and here are my [Css rules](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/eed0e1ef3d6098abdcea), so can somebody explain to me how I need to place those elements by proper way. Thanks!

Comment: start making a fiddle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position your flag **absolutely** and set **top, left, right, bottom** properties. Absolute positioned elements are removed from the natural document flow and you can align them where ever you want by setting their left, top, right, bottom properties

**Example**

```
<div class="box">

    <div class="inner-box">
    <p>dummy content</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Css

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}

.inner-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 20px auto;
```

Adjusting your margins can also help you position things, and the second value is extremely helpful to center things.